# Are delegation and websockets similar behind the scenes?

Tags: delegates, websocket, push

I'm just trying to figure out how these two things work. Obviously websocket's use push technology, so the client doesn't have to do long polling, or constantly refresh and check if something has changed (Kind of like an event listener).

But with delegation, like in objective C, are delegates constantly checking, by sending requests over and over again, to see if a method has been fired. Or is the information that a method has been fired PUSHed over to the delegates?

Or my third theory about delegates is, since they are of course in the same program, do the two classes (protocol and delegate class) always have an "open connection", kind of like Polling. Or is it like my second paragraph, where the information is truly being PUSHed.

Comment: WebSockets is not exactly a "push technology". It's a bi-directional full-duplex message based communication channel. Many push technologies can get low server to client (browser) latency, but with WebSockets you also get low client to server latency (and therefore low round-trip latency).

Comment: Thanks for the info Kanaka, really helpful!:D

Do you think you could give a go on explaining how delegation works behind the scene?

Comment: I made an answer and put what I could determine in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebSockets are a bi-directional full-duplex message based communication channel. Many push technologies can get low server to client (browser) latency, but with WebSockets you also get low client to server latency (and therefore low round-trip latency).

From my reading (I'm not an Objective-C expert), delegates are a just a way of creating a loose protocol (in the object sense, not in the network sense) between objects. I don't know the implementation details but I'm certain that there is no polling going on. The delegate methods are probably just looked up when needed. There is no need for an "open connection" or polling. Think of delegates as a way of doing function/method calls, not as a network transport (like WebSockets). This [Apple doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html) goes into deeper detail.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, it really means more than you know! This really helped with my understanding. As communication (networking) between computers, and even objects have been a confusing topic for me. But seriously, you have cleared up the whole thing! Thanks!